# Updating Thunderbird from apt to snap removed my config

Tags: apt, snap, thunderbird

How can I move my config from Thunderbird APT to Thunderbird SNAP?

It seems the update crashed in the middle, and I am left with an empty Thunderbird profile once I install Thunderbird snap.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the new thunderbird profile folder moved to `~/snap/thunderbird/common/.thunderbird`.

Steps to fix the issue:

- Open Thunderbird
- Go in the Help > Troubleshooting menu
- Click Open Profile Folder (`~/snap/thunderbird/common/*.default`)
- **Close Thunderbird**
- Remove all files from the opened Profile folder
- Copy `~/.thunderbird/*.default-release` other profile into the previous folder.
- Restart Thunderbird

It should be fixed.